# What states that base their government on Shariah law allow women in government?

Tags: islam, feminism

One of the more interesting turns in Afghanistan has been [the announcement that the Taliban would allow women to serve in government](https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/world/2021/08/17/taliban-invites-women-join-afghanistans-new-government/8161473002/)

> "The Islamic Emirate doesn't want women to be victims," Samangani said, using the militants' name for Afghanistan. "They should be in the government structure according to Shariah law."

> That would be a marked departure from the last time the Taliban were in power, when women were largely confined to their homes.

How many other states that base their laws on Shariah allow women to serve in governmental roles?

Comment: I wonder how sincere the announcement is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Afghanistan prior to the 2021 Taliban takeover adopted Shariah law as the highest legal authority in its constitution. So did Iraq following the Iraq War. So did Somalia in the last few years.

All of these countries allow women in government. Some mandate it. The list is not exhaustive.

Answer (score 1):

It is upon "how strict" is the interpretation of the Sharia done by that country. Reformist like Mohammad Bin Salman made sure Sharia is intact, the Constitution (Quran) is respected and at the same time score good in reports on women's rights.

The Taliban is reforming as it seems. It is natural to look them with suspicion for a lot many of the people.